# while trying to create procedure for insert getting following error in netbeans-7.2

Tags: mysql, triggers, netbeans-7.2

Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `mst_gate` (`gate_id`,`gate_name`,`status`)
        VALUES' at line 2

```
DELIMITER @@  
CREATE TRIGGER vms.ins_gate  
BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO `mst_gate` (`gate_id`,`gate_name`,`status`)   
        VALUES (new.gate_id, new.gate_name, new.status);  
  END @@  
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong trigger syntax,try

```
    DELIMITER @@  
    CREATE TRIGGER vms.ins_gate  BEFORE INSERT ON sometable
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO `mst_gate` (`gate_id`,`gate_name`,`status`)   
            VALUES (new.gate_id, new.gate_name, new.status);  
      END @@  
    DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `{BEFORE | AFTER} INSERT ON {TABLE NAME}`, and `FOR EACH ROW` clauses in your SQL.

Your `Create trigger` should be reading like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER vms.ins_gate BEFORE INSERT ON vms.gate
```

OR

```
CREATE TRIGGER vms.ins_gate AFTER INSERT ON vms.gate
```

***Possibly***:

```
DELIMITER @@
CREATE TRIGGER vms.ins_gate BEFORE INSERT ON vms.gate
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO mst_gate (gate_id,gate_name,status)
                VALUES (new.gate_id, new.gate_name, new.status);
  END
@@
DELIMITER ;
```

***Refer to***: [*MySQL: CREATE TRIGGER Syntax*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html)